# Dedupe MongoDB Collection

Tags: mongodb, duplicates, nosql

I'm new to NoSQL, so sorry if this is very basic. Let's say I have the following collection:

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 'x'
},
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 'y'
},
{
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: 'y'
}
```

I would like to run a "Dedupe" query on anything that matches:

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2
    ... (any other properties are ignored) ...
},
```

So after the query is run, either of the following remaining in the collection would be fine:

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 'y'
},
{
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: 'y'
}
```

OR

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 'x'
},
{
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: 'y'
}
```

**Just so long as there's only one document with a==1 and b==2 remaining.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you always want to ensure that only one document has any given `a`, `b` combination, you can use a unique index on `a` and `b`. When creating the index, you can give the `dropDups` option, which will remove all but one duplicate:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({a: 1, b: 1}, {unique: true, dropDups: true})
```

Comment: Damn it, forgot about that :)

Comment: This doesn't work for all possible cases (e.g. drop all dupes for {a:{$in:[1,2]}}) but is the only single command solution (although you'd probably want to drop the index straight after if you don't actually need the index)

Comment: "Changed in version 3.0: The dropDups option is no longer available."

Answer (score 1):

This answer hasn't been updated in a while. It took me a while to figure this out. First, using the Mongo CLI, connect to the database and create an index on the field which you want to be unique. Here is an example for `users` with a unique email address:

`db.users.createIndex({ "email": 1 }, { unique: true })`

The `1` creates the index, along with the existing `_id` index automatically created.

Now when you run `create` or `save` on an object, if that email exists, Mongoose will through a duplication error.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of any commands that will update your collection in-place, but you can certainly do it via temp storage.

1. Group your documents by your criteria (fields `a` and `b`)
2. For each group pick any document from it. Save it to temp collection `tmp`. Discard the rest of the group.
3. Overwrite original collection with documents from `tmp`.

You can do this with [MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) or upcoming [Aggregation Framework](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework) (currently in unstable branch).

I decided not to write code here as it would take the joy of learning away from you. :)